# Discord.js message attachments picture

Tags: node.js, discord

```
message.channel.sendMessage(text).attachments
["",{url:"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+icon+".png" }];
```

I made some bot, with `node-js ( discord.js )`.

I want to send message with picture(without URL) so, I found fuction attachments, in documentation.
But, when I put in message (text) and attachments some picture, in the console,I get:

> "Cannot read property '# < Object >' of undefined"

What should I do fix this problem?

Answer (score 9):

According to the docs, you will need to pass an object containing the file URL or a [FileOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FileOptions) object. You would do this like

```js
message.channel.send("some text", {
    file: "http://link.to/your.file" // Or replace with FileOptions object
});
```