# Make Discord bot send picture with message with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have a few pictures, all on imgur with direct image link (format: https://i.imgur.com/XXXXXX.jpg), and a Discord bot made with NodeJS.

I send messages like this:

```
bot.sendMessage({
    to: channelID,
    message: "My Bot's message"
});
```

I have tried this:

```
bot.sendMessage({
    to: channelID,
    message: "My Bot's message",
    file: "https://i.imgur.com/XxxXxXX.jpg"
});
```

but I only get the text. I have looked it up, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189796/discord-js-message-attachments-picture) was the only one to even come close to saying what I need to do, and it didn't work.

So how am I supposed to do this?

Here is how the bot is created:

```
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // My code
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`ClientUser.sendMessage` is deprecated](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=sendMessage), as is the `file` parameter in its options. You should be using `Channel.send(message, options)`, with `files` as an array of strings or [FileOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FileOptions).

```
bot.on('messageCreate' message => {
    message.channel.send("My Bot's message", {files: ["https://i.imgur.com/XxxXxXX.jpg"]});
});
```

If you want to stick to your deprecated methods, [`ClientUser.sendFile`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=sendFile) might be something of interest to you, though I do recommend you move over to the stuff that's more *current*.

Comment: I believe this is deprecated in 2019, but its the top result when googling how to upload an image. Now you can use `bot.uploadFile( )` and give it a path to a local file next to your bot, but you'll need to use the new message callback https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/

Comment: Works fine in 2021. It would be also nice to be able to use <canvas> element...

Comment: Just an edit I wanted to suggest. `message` should be changed to `messageCreate`

Answer (score 7):

You can send local files in v11.2 like this:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', message => {
    var prefix = '!'
    var msg = message.content;

    if (msg === prefix + 'image') {
        message.channel.send('Message that goes above image', {
            files: [
                "./image-to-send.png"
            ]
        });
    }
});

bot.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: This works for v12 as well, and you can omit the first part entirely if you just want to send an image without a message above it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the top results on google in 2019, I'm adding the new method of how to upload files with discord.io

First thing that's different is the `on()` function takes some additional parameters.

Next is that there's a new method called `uploadFile` that takes an `uploadFileOpts` object. the `file` can take a string that is a local path from your bot file to the image.

```
uploadFileOpts = {
  to: string,
  file: string|Buffer,
  filename?: string,
  message?: string
}
```

So, if you place your image next to your bot script, your code should look like this

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
 bot.uploadFile({
            to: channelID,
            file: 'myImage.jpg'
        });
}
```

If you still want to snag that image from the internet, you'll need to convert it into a `Buffer` object. However, storing the file locally is simpler.

Comment: Is there any method to send an image "on the fly" without actually save it on your server? I want to send some text embedded in an image and i'm using https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image to generate the image, tnx ooo i was missing the file: string|buffer option ... i have to do some digging

Comment: @Alex75 yes, you'll have to convert it to a buffer object. And I'm not quite sure how myself, thats why I avoided touching on that lol. I havent tested it, but common sense indicates it should work.

Comment: @PremierBromanov is it also possible with this to create a bot that logs all messages having a picture, so not the deleted ones, I know that doesn't work. but all messages maybe?

Comment: @Termatinator The bot will receive it's "on message" function for every message in the channel it is in. Thus, you can log any message with any given parameters. How to check if that message is an image i dont know off the top of my head. I'd log out some of that information to see what type of data you get.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using discord.io instead of Discord.js, refer to this syntax:

https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Methods/Channels.html

I'm still trying to get it to work.

Comment: Since this answer is two years old, I have now learned that Discord.js is a much superior API, so _please_ use Discord.js: https://discord.js.org/